# Family Polymorphism + Mixins?

Tags: scala, mixins, traits

I have a FAMILY of types that I want to modularly "enrich" using mixins. For example:

```
trait Family {
  self =>
  trait Dog {
    def dogname:String
    def owner:self.Person
  }
  trait Person {
    def name:String
    def pet:self.Dog
  }
}

trait SerializableFamily extends Family {
  trait Dog extends super.Dog {
    def toSimpleString:String = "Dog(" + dogname + ")"
  }
  trait Person extends super.Person {
    def toSimpleString:String = "Person(" + name + ") and his pet " + pet.toSimpleString
  }
}

trait SerializableFamily2 extends Family {
  trait Dog extends super.Dog {
    def toLoudString:String = "Dog(" + dogname.toUpperCase + ")"
  }
  trait Person extends super.Person {
    def toLoudString:String = "Person(" + name.toUpperCase + ") and his pet " + pet.toLoudString
  }
}
```

However, the above does not work ( Scala 2.9.1 ). The last expression fails to compile ( `pet.toSimpleString` ).

This is just a random strategy I picked out of several I tried: self typing, abstract types, super[...], etc.

I want to be able to do something like this, eventually:

```
val family = new Family with SerializableFamily with TraversableFamily with FooFamily {}
```

Where each mixin adds a set of cooperating methods to one or more types within the family.

This is a common pattern that I have seen solved by using implicit wrappers, pattern-matching based visitors, etc. But since it is just a recursive application of the regular mixin pattern I wonder if there might be a simpler way to achieve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error in your case is expected, since `Dog` and `Person` in mixins don't *override* `Dog` and `Person` in `Family`, so that `self.Person` still refers to `Family.Person`.

This may be closer to what you want

```
trait Family {
  // type DogType = Dog won't work because then two different mixins 
  // have incompatible DogType implementations
  type DogType <: Dog
  type PersonType <: Person

  trait Dog {
    def dogname:String
    def owner:PersonType 
  }
  trait Person {
    def name:String
    def pet:DogType 
  }
}

trait SerializableFamily extends Family {
  type DogType <: Dog
  type PersonType <: Person

  trait Dog extends super.Dog {
    def toSimpleString:String = "Dog(" + dogname + ")"
  }
  trait Person extends super.Person {
    def toSimpleString:String = "Person(" + name + ") and his pet " + pet.toSimpleString
  }
}
```

But then you have something yucky like

```
new Family with SerializableFamily with TraversableFamily with FooFamily {
  type DogType = super[SerializableFamily].Dog with super[TraversableFamily].Dog with super[FooFamily].Dog
}
```

Comment: This is mostly what I would have come up with, but this is not really what the OP wants if I understand correctly. He would like all the versions of `Dog` and `Person` to stack up at mix time, which I don't think is possible at all.

Comment: +1 for this, as this is probably the closest you can get. But explicitly mixing all the versions of the traits is quite verbose :(